Prevent caching of data URI as image source?
I have an img-tag and use a data-image base64 URI as source. Of course, browsers are caching this source. I do not want caching. If it would be a normal URL, I would add a random query-parameter value to prevent the caching.
What can I do to prevent the caching of this data-image base64 URI source?
img with data-image base64 URI:
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw==">
img with normal URL source and query-param to prevent caching:
<img src="https://foo?1234RandomString">
Since the original image is SVG, I could use a data-image SVG URI and add a custom attribute to this SVG to prevent caching. This works. I could also add the SVG as file to my deployment and use an URL with query param. I find both very ugly.
PS: Why do I need it?
I have a large list of img-tags. I would like to use the lazy loading mechanism to generate the actual source URL lazily in vue3.
Look at this extract. Initially, it sets the src to the data-image URI. When this is lazily loaded, the actual image source is created and set.
Problem: Lazy loading does not work in Chrome for cached source values. So, if initialSrc is cached for the first image, this mechanism will not work for all the other images.
<img :src="mySource" loading="lazy" @load="onLoad">

const initialSrc = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw=="

const imageSrc = ref()
const onLoad = async () => {
      if (!imageSrc.value) {
        imageSrc.value = await createRealSrc();
      }
    };

const mySource = computed(() => imageSrc.value ?? initialSrc)

There are some doubts in comments that data URIs are actually loaded via a request. edit: Trigger warning. More nuanced than it seems. Take a look further down and in the comments. They are:
Screenshot of network tab that shows a GET request to a data URI
Some more clarifications:
Let's say you have two img-tags in you document:
<img src="http://image.png" loading="lazy">
<img src="http://image.png" loading="lazy">

In this scenario the first img-tag will be loaded lazily. However, the second will not be loaded lazily, it will be loaded immediately after the first is loaded because its src can be taken from cache.
<img src="http://image.png" loading="lazy">
<img src="http://image.png?abc" loading="lazy">

In this scenario both will be loaded lazily because the URLs are different and cannot be taken from cache.
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw==" loading="lazy">
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw==" loading="lazy">

In this scenario the first img-tag will be loaded lazily. However, the second will not be loaded lazily, it will be loaded immediately after the first is loaded because its src can be taken from cache.
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWw==" loading="lazy">
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,sdfsdfs==" loading="lazy">

In this scenario both will be loaded lazily because the URIs are different and cannot taken from cache.
Why does the img-tag load immediately and not lazily when the image  can be taken from cache?
I do not know. This is the behavior that I see in Chrome. I do not know whether this part of the spec or an implementation detail in the current Chrome. It makes sense, though. Why doing a lazy load, when the image data can be taken from cache. In such a case, the lazy load does not bring any advantages. I still want lazy-load for my idea because I am trying to "mis-use" the lazy load to do an expensive operation lazily.
Is there really a GET request made when you use a data URI as source? According to Chrome network tab: Yes. Is it really real in real HTTP terms? I do not know. Edit: Do not get me wrong. There is no BE and it is not going out over TCP. So it is not real HTTP in that sense. I cannot say for sure how it is implemented inside Chrome. According to the dev tools, Chrome is treating it as a GET-request at least to some degree. Chrome records a HTTP-request and a HTTP-response to that request. Too me that ticks enough boxes to say it is a call in accordance to the HTTP protocol. Not implemented on top of TCP in this case. Real HTTP or not? Yeah, probably not.
Is the data URI really stored in cache? According to Chrome network tab: Yes. I think yes. As far as I understand, image data is stored in a cache in all browsers. It does not matter whether the source of the image data is a file or a data URI.
Is the source loaded when the image is loaded (and not earlier) even when it is a data URI? I say yes. I also think this is part of the spec (HTML-spec ??). But I do not have a link to prove it.

I'm not sure I understand the problem. What does "not work for all the other images" mean? If the image itself is cached, that should be fairly irrelevant, no? Does the fact that this image, which is the same for all image tags, is cached somehow interfere with the lazy loading script? Is that what you're saying? If so, how exactly? — Also, I'm not really sure what "cached" means in this context. The image data is right there, in the data URI. There's no request or anything being made anywhere, so what exactly is being cached?

@deceze If the initialSrc is cached, the img will be loaded immediately in Chrome. Not lazily. Therefore, all onLoads for all images will be executed immediately not lazily.

@deceze The image data (although inside a data URI) is still loaded via a request. Yes, maybe it is not a true request, but you see a request in the network tab and it behaves as a request as far as I can tell. This request can be done once (cached) or for each img individually (not cached). If it is only done once, no lazy loading for all images after the first image.

"is still loaded via a request" - perhaps its semantics here, but there is no HTTP request. A data URI is not a reference to the content it IS the content and therefore Not cacheable as an independent entity. If you are not seeing what you expect in the browser then maybe you should start by describing what you see / what you expect rather than assuming that this is a caching issue.

Your code replaces images which haven't been loaded with a placeholder image, and later, when the real image has been loaded, with the real image. So yes, I'd expect to see the placeholder image immediately. What else do you expect exactly?

@symcbean As far as I can tell this is not correct. It is loaded via a request. I will add screenshot that shows this to the question.

@deceze I expect that the onLoad function is called lazily.

A request to where? When exactly should onLoad be called?

You're barking up the wrong tree here. Seeing a "request" for data URIs is just an internal implementation detail. That's just how the browser deals with data URIs, but it's irrelevant. What you're really interested in is some vaguely defined lazy loading behaviour which doesn't work as you imagine. Concentrate on describing that better.

Because the initial placeholder image source is the same for all those images, the first one of them being scrolled into view, immediately triggers "loading" the placeholder image for all the ones further down as well - and due to the load event handler that cause the real source for those images to be loaded immediately now, whereas you want it to still be delayed, until those images have been scrolled into view - that's it, yes?

@deceeze When an img-tag is loaded lazily the onLoad is called when the image is near the viewport. When it is still far away from the viewport the onLoad is not called immediately. I added proof to the post that data URI are loaded via a GET request.

@CBroe Yes, exactly.

Peter: start again. Create a simple page with an image tag, a button and a script which replaces the image when the button is pressed. Look at your server logs as well as what you see in your browser. If this does not help you to resolve your issue then try posting a new question here.

I suppose you could easily make your Data URIs "different" ones, if you simply appended different comments after the actual SVG image? Currently, you are encoding <svg>...</svg> as the Data URI - if you encode <svg>...</svg><!-- X --> instead, and make the X an integer, that you increase by one with each image you output - then those would be different URIs, so the lazy-loading of the first one, should not trigger the replacement of all images further down.

@decee First of all, thank you for commenting. I personally believe, this is not correct. In my understanding the img source is always loaded via an GET request, when the img is loaded. For data URIs the GET request will always be answered from the browser cache. Whether this is a real HTTP request or a fake HTTP request, I cannot tell. But the behavior is like I described. I also do not think that this is Chrome-specific implementation detail, but I cannot proof it. So I get your point that this might rely on some vague behavior. And I take that as an important input.

It's kinda both. It is somewhat irrelevant that a fake request is made. But the behaviour is that once one image loads, all of them load, because they are all the same image. I can see now where you're coming from with wanting to prevent caching, but that's focusing on the wrong problem. It is the same image you're loading and the browser will only load it once, thus depending on onload here is… suboptimal. Is await createRealSrc() doing some expensive operation? Is it producing an actual URI, or another data URI?

@CBroe Thank you for commenting. This would solve problem. However, I was looking for a way to add or append something to the base64 data URI directly.

@deceze createRealSrc() It is doing a BE call and this call will generate a AWS S3 presigned-URL. So it is expensive. I want to prevent this for images that never make it to the viewport.

@deceze I guess a better way would be to not rely on the lazy loading mechanism of img-tag but to implement something based on scrollHeight or Intersection Observer. But, of course, this is lot more effort.

Yeah, for the builtin lazy behaviour to work as you expect, the URLs actually need to be unique. You could set the src immediately to a URL which will redirect to a signed URL, and have that lazy load…?!

@deceze This is a great idea. I consider this and discuss it with my BE colleague.

"I was looking for a way to add or append something to the base64 data URI directly." - if your base64-encoded SVG does not end on a "half value" (meaning, no = fillers at the end), then you should be able to "add" additional base64 encoded data to it via simple concatenation. https://3v4l.org/ksm4k - the base64_encode('foo') here would by your "static" SVG you already encoded earlier, and the base64_encode('bar'); would be what you add to the end, dynamically.

@CBroe Ah, yes. I did not think of this. I somehow treated the base64 string a a blob but of course it is not. This might be able to solve my initial issue as well. But I have to say the solution to circumvent the issue that was pointed out by deceze is very tempting.

"Is there really a GET request made…" — Browsers are structured around making network requests. The basic modus operandi is that they fetch a document from some URL, which contains references to other URLs, which they fetch in turn and display. data URIs are something of an aberration here: they're used in places where references to other things are expected, but they already contain the necessary data. So instead of having some weird special case for this, browsers keep all the existing plumbing as is, but no actual request needs to be made as the data is always in memory.

[continued] That's the only reason you see "requests" for those data URIs.

@deceze I do not know how it is implemented inside Chrome. But I still think, it could be a call in accordance to the HTTP protocol that is, obviously, not involving any TCP and is, obviously, completely implemented and executed inside Chrome. Chrome is recording a HTTP-request and HTTP-response in the dev-tools after all.
But this is just semantics and play of words from my side ;). In the strict sense it is not HTTP.
I am really thankful for the discussion and the solution that you proposed.

Lot's of confusion. And I am sorry for that. Here are some solutions that were posted and that I would like to highlight:
Use a "plain" SVG-based data URI instead of base64-encoded data URI.
With such a "plain" data URI, you can add a custom attribute with a random value to have a different URI for the same image:
data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' **custom-attribute="random value"** encoding='UTF-8'%3F%3E%3Csvg width='282.21' height='48'...
If you have an SVG-based base64-encoded data URI, add a base64-encoded comment.
Encode "<!-- random value -->" to base64 and add this to the base64-encoded data URI to make the URI different without changing the image itself. You can also use this instead of the custom attribute in the solution mentioned above.
Use a normal unique URL as image source that, when loaded lazily, does the lazy stuff.
This works when the lazy stuff is a BE call.
I.e. instead of loading a data URI lazily and than do a lazy BE call in onLoad. Use a unique BE URL as image source in the first place and do the call to BE directly when the image source is loaded lazily.

Typically this would be better off in an Edit of your original post, rather than commenting with an answer.
